# What Type Of Data does the Input File Contain?

Tags: text-processing, command-line, perl

I have a folder with more than 10000 text files. The files can be of two types:

**Type1: called “DNA”**

**Format:**

header information starting with “>”

Line 2 onwards contains only the following letters: “A”, “T”, “G”, “C”, “N”

**Example:**

Filename: “ABC123.tab”

```
  >DNA1_example
  TGTTGTTGTTGTTGCTGCTGTTGTTGCTGCTGTTGTTGTTGTTGTTGCTGCTGTTGTTGTTGTTGTTGCTGCTGCTGTTGTTGCTGTTGTCTTTGAGGTTGGAGATTAGGACGATTCGGCATGTTGTTGTTCCATGATCCGATCCCAACACCAGGACTAGGCTGTCCTTGCAAACTGATACCGGGACTCGATCTGGCACCAACTCCTGGCTGCGGAGAAAGTTGGGATCCGTGTTGTTGTTGTTGAAAACCTTGTGGAGGTGGTCCTATGCGAGGCGACACTTGAGCCGAATTAAACGGTGATAGCCGAGAAGATGGACCTCCAGGAGCAAAATTATTGCCGTTGTTGTTATTGACAATTTGTGCCTGAGGGCTTTGATTGTAGTTGCCACTATTGGCCGTGCTCAAACTGCTCATCGGACCGTGAGGTGAAAAAGGTGGTTGCATTGGGCGCTGACTGGGGGAGATTTGAGACGCTAGTGGCCCGCTACCTATTGGACTGC
```

**Type 2: called “protein”**

**Format:**

header information starting with “>”

Line 2 onwards contains only the following letters: G,A,L,M,F,W,K,Q,E,S,P,V,I,C,Y,H,R,N,D,T

**Example:**

Filename: “DEF123.tab”

```
    >Protein1_example
    MRCVLCYKNIAGNKLARFCVFSTSILLSLLSTQAQLSIIPQDELLAAEKMVNSSRWRLLD
```

What I would like to do is:

1)  Open the file.

2)  Skip line beginning with “>”

3)  Check if it contains either of these alphabets occurring: 
L,M,F,W,K,Q,E,S,P,V,I,Y,H,R,D in other lines.

4)  If yes, print “Protein”, else print “DNA”

Comment: Think of this as a programming exercise not a bioinformatics one. What's a fasta file? What's a sequence? In terms of these letter groups what are you looking for?

Comment: All of the nucleotide letters also appear as Protein letters; is the question "does the line contain letters *other* than ATGCN"?

Comment: @roaima: I have now included what a sequence and fasta format mean.

Comment: google search 1st result: https://www.biostars.org/p/82471/

Comment: @don_crissti: Yes, I checked that, I am not comfortable with Ruby or Python. That is why I asked here!

Comment: Per a comment over there: _"While it is possible to say that a sequence is not a nucleotide sequence, without additional information it is not possible to definitively say that a sequence is not protein sequence."_ ... now if that's true I don't see how you could validate those files with plain shell tools

Comment: I would like to suggest that you try to strip out as many of the the bioinformatics words as is realistically possible and leave just the computational part of the question.

Comment: @roaima: Yes, edited now!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Incase someone is interested in the future: Here is my quick and dirty way of doing it using perl:

```
  #!usr/bin/perl
  use warnings;
  use strict;
  open(FILE, "ABC123.fa");
  my $line_=<FILE>;
   $line_=readline(*FILE) if $line_=~/>/;
  close(FILE);
  if($line_ =~ /L|M|F|W|K|Q|E|S|P|V|I|Y|H|R|D/){
  print "Protein\n"
  }
  else {
   print "Nucleotide\n"
   }
```

I execute it using:

```
  perl format_tester.pl
```

before running this code each time, I just replace "ABC123.fa" to "DEF123.fa" using sed approach:

```
    sed -i 's/ABC123.fa/DEF123.fa/g' format_tester.pl
```

Comment: This would test no more than the first sequence line of a fasta file. For some protein fasta files, this may well only contain DNA symbols. Furthermore, if the file is not a fasta file, it would report random results depending on the file's content.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
for name in folder/*; do
    # skip this name if it's not the name of a file
    [ ! -f "$name" ] && continue

    awk 'NR == 1 && !/^>/ {
             printf("Not a fasta file: %s\n", FILENAME)
             skip=1; exit
         }
         !/^>/ && /[LMFWKQESPVIYHRD]/ {
             printf("Protein fasta file: %s\n", FILENAME)
             skip=1; exit
         }
         END {
             if (!skip) printf("Probably a DNA fasta file: %s\n", FILENAME)
         }' "$name"
done
```

This goes through all the names in the directory called `folder`.  It skips the names of subdirectories (non-files) and applies an `awk` script to the files it finds.

It then

1. Makes sure that the file is a fasta file by testing for a `>` at the beginning of the first line.  If there is no `>` at the start of the first line, it reports an error in the file and exits.
2. For each line not starting with `>`, it tests whether there's a protein symbol on the line.  If there is, it reports the file as a protein fasta file and exits.
3. At the end, if we get there, it's *possibly* a DNA fasta file and the code reports this.  Note that even however unlikely, it could still be a protein fasta file as the symbols for DNA amino acids are also part of the protein symbol set.

The `skip` variable is set to 1 when we're exiting due to having determined that the file is not a fasta file or if it's a protein fasta file. By testing this variable in the `END` block we know whether we arrived there due to an early `exit` or by running out of data (in which case it's probably a DNA fasta file).